# In what case should I create an own destructor?

Tags: c++, constructor, variable-assignment, destructor, operator-keyword

My compiler does automatically create a constructor, destructor and an assignment operator when I create an object. When should I implement them on my own?

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: c++, sorry I edited it

Comment: You mean *destructor* (not "deconstructor")

Comment: If you allocate memory in your class using new you likely will have to implement the rule of 3 or 5 instead of the rule of 0. That is if your class has ownership of the memory using a raw owning pointer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a destructor when you need to do something beyond what the generated one does, which is simply calling the destructors for every base and member.

In practice, this means there is some meaning that is beyond that of the individual members, and requires understanding multiple fields at the same time; OR

Adding [RAII/RFID](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) to the bare value; e.g. a smart pointer class frees the pointer that it holds.

Generally, if you need to write any one of the copy constructor, copy assignment operator, or destructor, then you need to write *all* of them.  This is known as the [Rule of Five](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#c21-if-you-define-or-delete-any-copy-move-or-destructor-function-define-or-delete-them-all).

Comment: Fixed -- sometimes the copy operation doesn't take when I use keyboard shortcuts in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason for writing your own destructor is to release dynamically allocated memory (e.g., created inside your class using `new`) or to call `delete` in (unsafe) pointers (e.g., deleting pointers that **are not** created using `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr`).

There are many good google results to learn more, this is a [simple example](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/destructors-c/).